# RestTemplate POST with query parameter without request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am trying a POST method with RestTemplate. I need my request to have only 1 query parameter, without body (e.g. `localhost:8080/predictions/init?date=xxxx`).

My current code is the following :

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/predictions/init";
String dateToGenerate = "xxxx";

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.setAll(map);

Map req_payload = new HashMap();
req_payload.put("date", dateToGenerate);

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(req_payload, headers);
restTemplateApi.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
```

The side of the REST controller I'm trying to call is the following :

```
 @PostMapping
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
 public PredictionGenerated initializeOnePrediction(@RequestParam @NotEmpty String date) { 
      .............................
      .............................
 }
```

I'm currently receiving `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: but you ARE setting a request payload...im not sure you fully understand the code you posted here. did you write it?

Comment: No. Can I set it to null? How can I set the date as a query parameter?

Comment: a query parameter is part of the URL. instead of posting to PREDICTION_ADAPTER_URL, you should post to PREDICTION_ADAPTER_URL + '?date=' + dateToGenerate   or something similar.

Comment: Yes it worked. It was that simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any many query param then set all in Multiple value Map as below.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> param= new 
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
param.put("date", datevalue);
```

Then create Http header add required content.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
header.setContentType("application/json");
```

Create the URL as below.

```
URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(base url)
        .queryParams(param)
        .build().toUri();

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(req_payload, headers);
restTemplateApi.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
```